# Excel formula to total cells containing numbers in brackets without the text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, countif

I would like to know if there's an Excel formula to input into Cell B2 to total up the number of 'A' hours in Row 1?

Thank you

[image: Excel]

Comment: Could you further explain the contents of "A hours in row 1" and give example?

Comment: Row 1 can contain A, B, WH. Only A and B has (). For example, A can be A (1 hours), A (2 hours), A (3 hours) etc. and a special condition when A is A (0.5 AM) it will be 4 hours. So based on the image, sum of A hours should be 9 hours + ? (which is the variation of hours e.g 1 or 2 or 3...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT(B1:F1,1)="A",IF(MID(B1:F1,4,2)="0.",4,--MID(B1:F1,4,1)),0))
```

Enter as array formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

EDIT relating to your comment

```
=+SUM(IF(LEFT(B10:F10,1)="A",IF(MID(B10:F10,4,2)="0.",4,--MID(B10:F10,4,SEARCH("h",B10:F10)-4)),0))
```

Comment: The cell cannot sum those with .5 hours. Example: 1.5 hours. Any way to solve that?

Comment: The new formula works! However, I found out that if I put B (0.5 AM) on top first and A (2 hours) below in one cell (E1), the formula will not sum that 'A' hour in that particular cell (E1). It has to be A (2 hours) on top first and then B (0.5 AM) below in E1 to work. Is there a way to make it work regardless if 'A' is on top or below a cell? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if I renamed 'A' to 'ADEL' what will be the updated formula?

Answer (score 0):

To change the formula by @JLCH to use ADEL instead of A you need to adjust the `LEFT(B10:F10,1)="A"` to instead read `LEFT(B10:F10,4)="ADEL"` so that it looks at the first 4 letters in the cells and checks if it matches "ADEL"

Comment: Changing it to LEFT(B10:F10, 4) gave me #VALUE!. I think MID(B10:F10,4,2) and --MID(B10:F10,4,SEARCH) might need to change too but I'm not sure what to change it to for the formula to work

Comment: Try `=+SUM(IF(LEFT(B10:F10,4)="ADEL",IF(MID(B10:F10,7,2)="0.",7,--MID(B10:F10,7,SEARCH("h",B10:F10)-7)`

Comment: Changing it to `=+SUM(IF(LEFT(B10:F10,4)="ADEL",IF(MID(B10:F10,7,2)="0.",4,--MID(B10:F10,7,SEARCH("h",B10:F10)-7)` due to ADEL (0.5 AM) = 4 hours. Now the only issue is the top and bottom order

Comment: My mistake I forgot to include the closing `),0))` from @JLCH original formula at the end. `=+SUM(IF(LEFT(B10:F10,4)="ADEL",IF(MID(B10:F10,7,2)="0.",4,--MID(B10:F10,7,SEARCH("h",B10:F10)-7)),0))` this first checks if the cell contains ADEL and if it does it then checks to see if it is a 0.5 and returns 4, if not it searches for the the 'h' and returns the hour if it finds it else it returns 0.